# SQL Case statement copying an excel formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, excel-formula

I have an excel report I am trying to convert to an SSRS report using a stored proc. In the existing excel (not written by me) has a formula as follows

```
=IF( [Date TCY Vacated]="",0,IF([Date TCY Tenanted]="",Summary!$B$3 - ( [Date TCY Vacated]+1), IF( ( [Date TCY Tenanted] -1)- ( [Date TCY Vacated] +1) <0,0,  ( [Date TCY Tenanted] -1)- ( [Date TCY Vacated] +1)   )   ))
```

I am trying to convert this into a sql case statement.

I'm expecting this to be an INT so I can sum the column up to get total days vacant from the property

```
Case When [Date TCY Vacated] Is Null Then '0' 
                    else case when [Date TCY Tenanted] = '' then @End - ([Date TCY Vacated]+1)
                    else case when ([Date TCY Tenanted] - 1) - ([Date TCY Vacated] +1) < 0 then 0
                    else  Convert(Varchar(30),[Date TCY Tenanted],120) - Convert(Varchar(30),[Date TCY Vacated],120) end end end as 'Void Days'
```

Tried that but not working, I'm trying to add sample data but unsure how. All fields are date fields, expected results would be 2018-02-14 - 2018-02-12 = 2 (days).

Comment: Sample data and desired results help more than an Excel formula.  What does the data look like?

Comment: What does your case expression look like? Because that seems pretty straight forward... e.g. `case when [Date TCY Vacated]='' then 0 when [Date TCY Tenanted]='' then...` etc

Comment: Hi Gordon, I'm rubbish at posting questions.. not sure how to give sample data, Essentially the columns are all date fields, 
Void Start Date Available to Let Date Offer Date Accept Date Let Date Void Start Date Calc Void End Date Calc Date TCY Vacated Date TCY Tenanted
13/12/2017 27/12/2017 NULL NULL 13/12/2017 14/12/2017 13/12/2017 13/12/2017 NULL
20/03/2018 3/04/2018 NULL NULL 20/03/2018 21/03/2018 19/03/2018 NULL NULL

Comment: ZLK updated questions with current not working code

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275458/how-do-i-paste-spreadsheet-data-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason you are having problems is that you are using standard mathematical operators to work with dates.

The below example is based on your provided samples with some tweaks to use date functions instead.  It may not perfectly reflect your desired outcome but hopefully will take you most of the way there:

```
CREATE TABLE #a ([Date TCY Vacated] DATE, [Date TCY Tenanted] DATE)

INSERT INTO #a ([Date TCY Vacated], [Date TCY Tenanted])
    VALUES ('2018-02-10', '2018-02-08')
            ,(NULL, '2018-02-08')
            ,('2018-02-10', NULL)
            ,('2018-02-10', '2018-02-28')


DECLARE @End DATE = GETDATE()

SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN [Date TCY Vacated] IS NULL
            THEN    0
            ELSE    CASE WHEN [Date TCY Tenanted] IS NULL 
                        THEN    DATEDIFF(d, @End, DATEADD(d, 1, [Date TCY Vacated]))
                        ELSE    CASE WHEN DATEADD(d, -1, [Date TCY Tenanted]) < DATEADD(d, 1, [Date TCY Vacated])
                                    THEN    0
                                    ELSE    DATEDIFF(d, DATEADD(d, -1, [Date TCY Tenanted]), DATEADD(d, 1, [Date TCY Vacated]))
                                END
                    END
        END
FROM #a
```

In particular this code uses DATEADD and DATEDIFF instead of '+' and '-' to ensure all operations occur in days.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Case statement, but a SQL version of your Excel function.  It should work in SSRS

```
Declare @tcyv Int = 1
Declare @tcyt Int = ''
Declare @summ Int = 300

Select iif(@tcyv = '', 0,
            iif(@tcyt = '', @summ - (@tcyv+1),
            iif(((@tcyt-1) - (@tcyv+1)) < 0, 0,
                 (@tcyt-1) - (@tcyv+1)))) As x
```

With the CASE statement:

```
Select Case When @tcyv = '' Then 0
            When @tcyt = '' Then @summ - (@tcyv+1)
            When((@tcyt-1) - (@tcyv+1)) < 0 Then 0
             Else    (@tcyt-1) - (@tcyv+1) End As x
```

Result:

```
298
```

Comment: I'm not clear on how you're working with your dates - but this hopefully helps you go forward.